# Java: setting value of int multiple times

Tags: java, math, integer, int

I use this method to get a random location outside the screen to spawn all the zombies on.

```
public void initZombie(){ 
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                int randomXSpawn = (int) Math.random() * -300 + -50;
                int randomYSpawn = (int) Math.random() * -100 + 800;
                int[][] spawn = {{randomXSpawn,randomYSpawn}};
                for(int j = 0; j < spawn.length; j++){
                    zombie.add(new Zombie(spawn[j][0],spawn[j][1]));
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem that I am having with this is that the two ints that gets the random location only run once so therefor every single zombie spawns at the exact same place inside of each other. How would I be able to get the ints to run multiple times so that the zombies spawn at different locations? I have tried to put them inside of the run() method instead and then they run two times so that the first zombie spawns in one location and then the 99 other zombies spawn at another location inside of each other.

Comment: move the calls to `Math.random()` to inside the inner `for`, or am I missing something?

Comment: `random` numbers are commonly based off of time, so It's looking like you're getting the same random seed because you're calling them so close to each-other.  I'm certain that java has a `random.next` functionality that you would invoke from a `random` object.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting `Math.random()` to an integer which floors the value. Since `Math.random()` generates a double that is `0 <= x < 1`, it will *always* be rounded to 0. That is why you are getting the exact same spawn position.

You need to add parenthesis to your cast:

```
int randomXSpawn = (int) (Math.random() * -300 + -50);
int randomYSpawn = (int) (Math.random() * -100 + 800);
```

Comment: +1 This is the actual problem with the code. `Math.random()` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd use the [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%2) object, and I'd call the `nextInt` function

```
Random rnd = new Random();

for(...)
{
    int randInt = rnd.nextInt(300) //300 is the maximum
}
```

Comment: More precisely: `rnd.nextInt(300);` will return integers between 0 (inclusive) and 300 (exlusive). It'll never return larger integer than 299. Just to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

You don't index your `spawn` array. Actually I don't think you even need one. Try this

```
public void initZombie(int maxZombies){
        Random r=new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < maxZombies; i++){
                zombie.add(new Zombie(r.nextInt(MAX_X), r.nextInt(MAX_Y));
        }
    }
```

If you later need to recall the spawn position of a zombie, you can save it as a private int in the zombie instance.

Also the original code will give you negative coordinates because you multiply with a negative constant. And even if it did work you'd end up with more zombies than you'd want because the `new Zombie()` code runs in an inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things causing problems with the code. As Supericy said, you're accidentally casting all of your random numbers too soon, truncating their values, and as SJuan76 mentioned in a comment, your for loop isn't quite set up right. (It works, but it can be much cleaner.)

---

**First, the casting issue:** When you cast a double to an int, the decimal portion is rounded down.

```
int num = (int) 0.999; //num == 0
```

`Math.random()` always returns a double between 0 and 1, so when cast to an int, it's always truncated to zero as well.

So that means your line

```
int randomXSpawn = (int) Math.random() * -300 + -50;
```

is evaluated like this:

```
int randomXSpawn = (int) Math.random() * -300 + -50;
int randomXSpawn = (int) 0.xxxx * -300 + -50;
int randomXSpawn = 0 * -300 + -50;
int randomXSpawn = -50;
```

To fix this, simply add parenthesis to force the multiplication and addition to happen before the casting, like Supericy said:

```
int randomXSpawn = (int) (Math.random() * -300 + -50);
int randomYSpawn = (int) (Math.random() * -100 + 800);
```

---

**Second, the for loops:** This is what you have now. It works correctly, but it could be written more clearly.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int randomXSpawn = (int) Math.random() * -300 + -50;
    int randomYSpawn = (int) Math.random() * -100 + 800;
    int[][] spawn = {{randomXSpawn,randomYSpawn}};
    for(int j = 0; j < spawn.length; j++){
        zombie.add(new Zombie(spawn[j][0],spawn[j][1]));
    }
}
```

What happens during a single iteration of the outer for loop?

```
    //int i = 0;
    int randomXSpawn = (int) Math.random() * -300 + -50;
    int randomYSpawn = (int) Math.random() * -100 + 800;
    int[][] spawn = {{randomXSpawn,randomYSpawn}};
    for(int j = 0; j < spawn.length; j++){
        zombie.add(new Zombie(spawn[j][0],spawn[j][1]));
    }
```

First, you generate two random numbers:

```
    int randomXSpawn = (int) Math.random() * -300 + -50;
    int randomYSpawn = (int) Math.random() * -100 + 800;
```

Then, you store those numbers so you can get to them later:

```
    int[][] spawn = {{randomXSpawn,randomYSpawn}};
```

Finally, you enter into the final for loop:

```
    for(int j = 0; j < spawn.length; j++){
        zombie.add(new Zombie(spawn[j][0],spawn[j][1]));
    }
```

What happens in there? We know that `spawn` is a two-dimensional array. Since you just declared it above, we also know that it has dimensions `[1][2]`. This means that the for loop will iterate once: when `j = 0`, because when `j = 1` on the next iteration, `j < spawn.length` will no longer be true.

Because of how you declared `spawn`, we know that `spawn[0][0] == randomXSpawn` and `spawn[0][1] == randomYSpawn`, so the line in the middle of the inner for loop effectively does this:

```
        zombie.add(new Zombie(randomXSpawn,randomYSpawn));
```

This suggests a way to make your code more clear: You can remove the `spawn` array and the inner for loop in order to call the `Zombie` constructer with `randomXSpawn` and `randomYSpawn` directly.

This is what the change would look like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int randomXSpawn = (int) Math.random() * -300 + -50;
    int randomYSpawn = (int) Math.random() * -100 + 800;
    zombie.add(new Zombie(randomXSpawn,randomYSpawn));
}
```

---

Putting both changes together, we get this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int randomXSpawn = (int) (Math.random() * -300 + -50);
    int randomYSpawn = (int) (Math.random() * -100 + 800);
    zombie.add(new Zombie(randomXSpawn,randomYSpawn));
}
```

If you don't like my suggested restructuring of the for loops, you don't have to change that. I think the way you have them now works correctly. It's just my opinion that it's difficult to read, and if you disagree, that is allowed =). The first change about using parenthesis to control casting is what is causing the problem you mentioned in your question, though, and needs to be taken care of.